# Euclidean norm using R

Tags: r

I want to use the matlab syntax below in term of R code, actually **X** is a **nxm** matrix:

```
Hs(i,j)=norm(X(i,:)-X(j,:))^2;
Hs(j,i)=Hs(i,j);
Hs=exp(-Hs/3);
```

Here is my R code:

```
Hs[i,j]=sqrt(sum((X[i,]- X[j,])^2))
Hs[i,j]=Hs[j,i]
Hs=exp(-Hs/3)
```

But the problem the result output was matrix 3x3 with all element =1. Please help.

Comment: But why it comes with all element = 1?

Comment: is this true in term of gaussian kernel matrix?, yes the loop i over 1:n but some matlab they mentioned it j over 1:i and there is also j over i+1:n, what is the difference

Comment: @李哲源 thanks my friend I did it

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer:

```
#Euclidean matrix

euc.dist <- function(p, q) {
    ed<-sqrt(sum((p - q)^2))
  return((ed))
}

#Gaussian kernel nxn matrix

get.gramm.nn <- function(X) {
  n <- dim(X)[1]
  Gramm<- matrix(0, n, n) #initializes Gramm array #i=index for rows
               #j=index for columns Gramm<-as.matrix(Gramm) # Gramm matrix
  for (i in 1:n) {
    for (j in 1:n) {
      Gramm[i, j] <- euc.dist(X[i,], X[j,])
    }
  } 
Gramm<- exp(-(Gramm)^2)
return(Gramm)
}
```